# Adding bean validation dependency jar broke my project & tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I took over a Spring Boot project that had a lot of POJO fields annotated with `@NotBlank` (from `javax.validation.constraints`).

I added validations to my new POJO and added a dependency to my `pom.xml` which was not there - `org.springframework.boot` => `spring-boot-starter-validation`

Well, pulling in that dependency broke a bunch of tests for other classes that had fields annotated with `@Notblank`

So my question is: Does `@NotBlank` have any effect if that validation dependency jar is not pulled in?

The Spring Boot version is 2.6.6 (Spring version 5.3.18)

Comment: What is your version of `spring boot`?

Comment: Spring boot start parent is 2.6.6  (spring version 5.3.18)

Comment: Edit Question to add details, rather than post Comments.

Comment: Annotations by themself do nothing, so likely your project didn't have a validator before, and now one is loaded and configured, and it causes issues because things don't validate. However, to make this really answerable, you need to provide a [mre].